# Flutter: determine active page in the pageController

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, flutter-pageview

I manually coded a TabPageSelector allowing users to see their progress in scrolling through the pages (from a PageView.builder). However I cannot seem to successfully pass-down the _activePage to the CircleAvatar that needs to change color.
My problem seems to be at:

> ```
>   _onPageViewChange(int page) {
>     setState(() {
>       _activePage = page;
>     });
>
>     print("Current Page: $_activePage");
>   }
> ```

If I don't use the setState, then I can scroll through the pages and check the _activePage when printing it. However, if I use the setState (so that the _activePage variable gets automatically updated in the CircleAvatar, I can no longer scroll through the pages. I just cannot figure out what goes wrong. Please have a look and give me some suggestions. Please see my code below:

> ```
> class BookFeeder extends StatefulWidget {
>   const BookFeeder({super.key});
>   static const String id = 'BookFeeder';
>
>   @override
>   State<BookFeeder> createState() => _BookFeederState();
> }
>
> class _BookFeederState extends State<BookFeeder> {
>   //declare page controller
>   final PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
>
>   //Hide the AppBar and bottomNavigationBar
>   bool _showAppBar = false;
>   bool _showBottomBar = false;
>
>   // Declare starting page
>   int _activePage = 0;
>
>   _onPageViewChange(int page) {
>     setState(() {
>       _activePage = page;
>     });
>
>     print("Current Page: $_activePage");
>   }
>
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Scaffold(
>       appBar: _showAppBar
>           ? AppBar(
>               leadingWidth: 120,
>               backgroundColor: const Color(
>                 (0XFF293D63),
>               ),
>               leading: IconButton(
>                 onPressed: () {
>                   //print('Go Back Pressed');
>                   Navigator.pop(context);
>                 },
>                 icon: SvgPicture.asset('images/button_goback_clean_svg.svg'),
>               ),
>               //Add to the Appbar the favourites, quizz and settings and next page
>               //title: Text('First Page'),
>               centerTitle: true,
>               actions: [
>                 IconButton(
>                   iconSize: 45,
>                   onPressed: () {
>                     Navigator.pushNamed(context, MySettings.id);
>                   },
>                   icon:
>                       SvgPicture.asset('images/button_settings_clean_svg.svg'),
>                 ),
>               ],
>             )
>           : null,
>
> // make the navigationbar look better
>       bottomNavigationBar: _showBottomBar
>           ? BottomAppBar(
>               shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
>               color: Colors.white,
>               elevation: 9,
>               child: StreamBuilder(
>                 stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
>                     //Below defines which collection to get
>                     .collection('fishingmonkey')
>                     .snapshots(),
>                 builder: (context,
>                     AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
>                         snapshot) {
>                   if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
>                     return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
>                   }
>
>                   return Row(
>                     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
>                     children: [
>                       SizedBox(
>                         height: 70,
>                         //width: 300,
>                         child: ListView.builder(
>                           scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
>                           shrinkWrap: true,
>                           itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
>                           itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
>                             padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 16, 8, 16),
>                             child: InkWell(
>                               onTap: () {
>                                 print("Current Page: $_activePage");
>                                 // _pageController.animateToPage(index,
>                                 //     duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
>                                 //     curve: Curves.easeIn);
>                               },
>                               child: CircleAvatar(
>                                 radius: 10,
>                                 backgroundColor: _activePage == index
>                                     ? const Color(0XFF293D63)
>                                     : Colors.blue[100],
>                               ),
>                             ),
>                           ),
>                         ),
>                       )
>                     ],
>                   );
>                 },
>               ),
>             )
>           : null,
>
>       body: GestureDetector(
>         onTap: () {
>           setState(() {
>             _showAppBar = !_showAppBar;
>             _showBottomBar = !_showBottomBar;
>           });
>         },
>         child: ScrollConfiguration(
>           behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(
>             dragDevices: {
>               PointerDeviceKind.touch,
>               PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
>             },
>           ),
>           child: ScrollEdgeListener(
>             edge: ScrollEdge.end,
>             edgeOffset: 0,
>             continuous: false,
>             debounce: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
>             dispatch: true,
>             listener: () {
>               print('end reached');
>               Navigator.pop(context);
>             },
>             child: ScrollConfiguration(
>               behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(
>                 dragDevices: {
>                   PointerDeviceKind.touch,
>                   PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
>                 },
>               ),
>               child: StreamBuilder(
>                 stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
>                     //Below defines which collection to get
>                     .collection('fishingmonkey')
>                     .snapshots(),
>                 builder: (context,
>                     AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
>                         snapshot) {
>                   if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
>                     return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
>                   }
>                   //below is going to create all the different Pageviews() depending on the number of 'docs'
>                   // this can be NULL (hence !) and .length provides the number
>
>                   return PageView.builder(
>                     onPageChanged: _onPageViewChange,
>                     controller: _pageController,
>                     itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
>                     itemBuilder: (context, index) => BookContent(
>                       //here you will request the data from 'docs' and request the whole index (starts from 0; can also do index +1)
>                       //
>                       snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data(),
>                     ),
>                   );
>                 },
>               ),
>             ),
>           ),
>         ),
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Can someone please help? I know the Ternary Operator in the CircleAvatar is working correctly if I just pass in a random number. I just don't seem to get the variable of the _activePage correctly in there. Thank you so much